# How can I correctly calculate the position opening number and send it to the exchange in Python?

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, cryptocurrency

I have a problem opening an order in API BingX. I hope I can pay attention to you for my purpose

When I want to open a position in the exchange (without using API, as in the attached photo), whatever the amount of my balance is, or selecting the MAX option, my entire balance (which is USDT) will participate in the transaction. And coins are bought according to my balance
[selecting the MAX option in BingX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqDTT.png)
But there are 2 problems for me
My first problem is that my calculation in Python is not like that (the code and function I use)

```
def get_max_position_available():
    to_use = float(bingx.get_perpetual_balance()['data']['balance']['balance'])
    # price = float(bingx.get_latest_price('SHIB-USDT'))
    price = float(bingx.get_latest_price('ETH-USDT'))
    decide_position_to_use = (to_use / price)

    print("to_use :",to_use )
    print("price :",price)
    print("decide_position_to_use :",decide_position_to_use)

    return decide_position_to_use
```

My second problem is that my calculation in Python if there are decimals in the obtained number is different from the calculation of the exchange when I want to open the transaction manually.

for example:

in BTC/USDT:
If my balance is `55.7021` and the current price of Bitcoin is

`43085.1`, my calculated number in Python will be
`0.0012928390557292429`

But in the manual transaction, the amount of the deal will be `0.0012` for me

How should I determine the decimals to open the transaction?

Or in other words, how can I correctly calculate the position opening number and send it to the exchange?

In another example: ETH

My balance amount: `55.7021`

ETH price at the moment: `2238.99`

My calculation in Python: `0.024878226343127932` the amount of ETH

that I can buy with the amount of the current balance

The amount that the exchange calculates for me: `0.02`

I was also told somewhere that I need to put the numbers in the format `"0.00001800"` in the request to the exchange. If that is correct, how can I do this to trade in all coins?

Comment: In my calculations, I took into account the exchange fee and the amount obtained was almost the same, but the format of the decimal amount for each coin is still questionable for me.
For example, BTC 0.0012 has four decimal places, but SHIB coin does not have a decimal place 5359478

Comment: when the first digit is a `1` use 2 significant digits, otherwise use 1 significant digit, do not apply rounding, convert number to string and manipulate the string